# Android: Search location by Name without using Google Places or Maps SDK

Tags: android, location

I'm looking for a way to search a location using name. The location being an object with longitude and latitude data.

I want to achieve this without using Places SDK or Maps SDK, as they are paid services in the long run (if I'm not mistaken)

I've tried using Geocoder, but it seems like it only works if you are searching for a country. Ideally, I would like to be able to search for city as well. GeoCoder returns an empty list for this usecase. Using LocationManager only allows me to get the last known location of the user, so that's not it either.

Is there such a way to achieve this?

Comment: You should try using HereMap SDK. https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder-autocomplete/dev_guide/topics/request-constructing.html
You also can use built in classes for this task.

Comment: use this tutorial https://medium.com/skillhive/android-google-places-autocomplete-feature-bb3064308f05

Answer (score 0):

I tried Geocoder again, and it seems my first take wasn't accurate. The requirement for Geocoder seems to be that you need to provide an actual name that matches any entry, otherwise it's gonna be null.

For the meantime, I think this should work for me. But if there's any other way that allows me to search for any location without complete name would be better

Answer (score 0):

You can use a few open-source maps for achieving this like OpenStreetMaps or HereMaps.